# jquery calculation works in jsfiddle example, but not in main code

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JWTQk/2/) where a jquery function is used in able to make a calculation between the number entered in the text input and subtracting the number with the "Total Marks" number per question.

Have a play around in the jsfiddle, in question 1 change the values in the text input and you will see the total marks change with in the same question block. For question 2 it is a readonly box but the reason it is readonly is because it is a single answer. If a question has a single answer then the text input should be readonly else if multiple answers then it should  not be readonly.

The fact is though is that I want the jquery function to work with the code below but it doesn't at the moment. These are the problems I have which needs to be fixed:

- The total marks should not equal 5, it should equal the value of `$searchMarks[$key]`, as each question could have a different total marks
- At the moment for the code below it does not perform the calculation
- Finally it is not making the text input readonly if question only contains single answer.

My question is that how should the code below be setup so that it can work exactly the same as the jsfiddle?

Below is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/basic.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {

    var $inputs = $('input.individualMarks');

$inputs.filter(function() {
    return $(this).prop('readonly') === true;
}).each(function() {
    var $input = $(this);

});

$inputs.filter('[data-q_group]').keyup(function() {
    var $group = $inputs.filter('[data-q_group="' + $(this).data('q_group') + '"]');
    var $marks = $group.eq(0).closest('tr').find('td.noofmarkstd');
    var markVal = <?php $searchMarks ?>;
    $group.each(function() {
        markVal -= ($(this).val() || 0)
    })
    $marks.text(markVal)

})

});

    </script>   

    </head>

    <body>

    <form id="QandA" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">

    <?php 

    echo "<table border='1' id='markstbl'>
          <tr>
          <th class='questionth'>Question No.</th>
          <th class='questionth'>Question</th>
          <th class='answerth'>Answer</th>
          <th class='answermarksth'>Marks per Answer</th>
          <th class='noofmarksth'>Total Marks</th>
          </tr>\n";
    $previous_question_id = null;
    $rowspans = array_count_values($searchQuestionId);
    foreach ($searchQuestionContent as $key=>$question) {

        // removed logic, not necessary to set empty strings if you're skipping them

        echo '<tr class="questiontd">'.PHP_EOL;

        if ($previous_question_id != $searchQuestionId[$key]) {
            echo '<td class="questionnumtd" name="numQuestion" rowspan="'.$rowspans[$searchQuestionId[$key]].'">'.htmlspecialchars($searchQuestionId[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
            echo '<td class="questioncontenttd" rowspan="'.$rowspans[$searchQuestionId[$key]].'">'.htmlspecialchars($question).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
        }

        echo '<td class="answertd" name="answers[]">';
        echo $searchAnswer[$key];
        echo '</td>' ;
        echo '<td class="answermarkstd"><input class="individualMarks" name="answerMarks[]" id="individualtext" type="text" /></td>' . PHP_EOL;

        if ($previous_question_id != $searchQuestionId[$key]) {
            echo '<td class="noofmarkstd" rowspan="'.$rowspans[$searchQuestionId[$key]].'">'.htmlspecialchars($searchMarks[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
        }

        // moved this to the end
        if ($previous_question_id != $searchQuestionId[$key]) {
            $previous_question_id = $searchQuestionId[$key];
        }
    }
            echo '</tr>';
            echo "</table>" . PHP_EOL;

            ?>


    </form>
```

Comment: Don't you need `$(document).ready`?

Comment: please only post pertinent code..  sql queries have nothing to do with javascript

Comment: @njk Oh do I, sorry didn't know that, I will in document ready and see what happens

Comment: @nkj I hae included document ready but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Your code behaved the same locally as it did in jsFiddle after enclosing it within $(document).ready (As mentioned in a comment above).

```
$(function() {<your code>});
```

Maybe you forgot to src jquery?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No I included the jquery source already, but the code with the document ready function still doesn't do what I required (the three bulet points mentioned in question) I will update code in my question to include src jquery and document.ready()